# Why am I not able to call a pure function accessing an enum from a library?

Tags: solidity, library, enum

I'm working on a [token-gated NFT distribution site](https://chiev.es). I've divided up the 256 bits of the token id & I'm using various parts to represent different aspects of a permissioning system.

Central to the architecture are role gating tokens. Pretty much every operation is goverened by an associated role that a user can have by possessing a token with a particular id.

I'm using an `enum` to lay out the bits for the roles, and I would like the contract to be the source of truth as to what roles exist.

To this end, I have a function:

```
  function roleNameByIndex(Role index)
    public pure returns (string memory name)
  {
    if(index == Role.Superuser) return "Superuser";
    if(index == Role.Minter) return "Minter";
    if(index == Role.Caster) return "Caster";
      // ⋮
  }
```

And a corresponding function:

```
  function roleIndexForName(string memory roleName)
    public pure returns (Role role)
  {
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(roleName));
    if(hash == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('Superuser'))) {
      return Role.Superuser;
    }
    if(hash == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('Minter'))) {
      return Role.Minter;
    }
    if(hash == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('Caster'))) {
      return Role.Caster;
    }
      // ⋮
  }
```

They operate in terms of a [`Role` `enum`](https://github.com/MetaFam/chievemints/blob/45bf542ec25516135f908ba823ce90cbc2c469d4/packages/contracts/src/BulkDisbursableNFTs.sol#L117-L165) that looks like:

```
  enum Role {
    Reserved0,
    Superuser,
    Minter,
    Caster,
      // ⋮
    Reserved−1
  }
```

All seems well & good. The functions worked when they were directly in the token contract, but moving them to the library seems to have broken them.

Here is a simple example of what doesn't work:

```
library Bits {
  enum Role {
    Reserved00,
    Superuser,
    Minter,
    Caster,
    Transferer
  }

  function roleNameByIndex(Role index)
    public pure returns (string memory name)
  {
    if(index == Role.Superuser) return "Superuser";
    if(index == Role.Minter) return "Minter";
    if(index == Role.Caster) return "Caster";
    if(index == Role.Transferer) return "Transferer";
      }

  function roleValueForName(string memory roleName)
    public pure returns (Role role)
  {
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(roleName));
    if(hash == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('Superuser'))) {
      return Role.Superuser;
    }
    if(hash == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('Minter'))) {
      return Role.Minter;
    }
    if(hash == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('Caster'))) {
      return Role.Caster;
    }
    if(hash == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('Transferer'))) {
      return Role.Transferer;
    }
    revert(string(abi.encodePacked('Unknown role type: ', roleName)));
  }
}
```

To see for yourself:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/MetaFam/chievemints.git
yarn && yarn hh:node &; yarn hh:test
```

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example? In the question you should provide details about the problem, not how you arrive at the issue.

Comment: @Ismael, I tidied it up a bit and cut out all the operational stuff.

Comment: I don't see any problem. What do you mean exactly by "it doesn't work"? it reverts, it does nothing, it returns something else, .. .